# Question about Lie superalgebra.

Tags: reference-request, physics, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics

What are the generators and relations for the Lie superalgebra $\mathfrak{psu}(2, 2 | 4)$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article [arXiv:0505234](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0505234), "Non-linear Realization of $\operatorname{PSU}(2,2|4)$ on the Light-Cone" by Pierre Ramond et al. has details and further references.

The algebra has 30 bosonic generators forming direct product of conformal algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2,2) \sim \mathfrak{so}(4,2)$ (15 generators) and internal $\mathfrak{su}(4) \sim \mathfrak{so}(6)$ (also 15 generators), as well as 32 fermionic generators.

Fermionic generators form a representation of $\mathfrak{su}(2,2) \otimes \mathfrak{su}(4)$ under adjoint action of bosonic sub-algebra.